# how to handle warning: PHP Warning unable to load php_openssl.dll on centos server No such file in unknown on line 0

Tags: warnings, laravel-5.5, laravel-artisan, php-openssl

thanks everyone,
when I run php artisan tinker or any other php artisan command on my centos machine, it works find, but it shows warning,

```
PHP Warning unable to load dynamic library '/usr/*/*/*/php_openssl.dll' on centos server No such file in unknown on line 0
```

and then everything seems to work fine, how can I handle this warning?
is it something important? we are using this application internally,

Comment: Is your directory for PHP extensions set properly?  Is openssl missing when you run `php -m`? Is openssl installed?

Comment: when I ran php -m, I found openssl is missing, I will install it,